# it there a native <alert> html tag?

Tags: html, angular, alert

I saw this angular2 - html template

```
<alert *ngFor="let alert of alerts;let i = index" [type]="alert.type" dismissible="true" (close)="closeAlert(i)">
  {{ alert?.msg }}
</alert>
```

But I cannot see `<alert>` is a native html tag.

What is is then? What its behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<alert>` is not a native HTML control. In Angular2, it could be a **custom component** 
**OR**
Here, I think it is a third party component made in 3rd party library like **[ng2-bootstrap Alert](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/alerts)**.

Comment: what is the difference between these two attributes? `[type]="alert.type" dismissible="true"` why is only one of them covered with `[]` ?

Comment: Look I provided link in the answer. please go through that.

Comment: in your link I saw both `type` and `dismissible` are `Alert properties` then why is  [type]="alert.type" dismissible="true"?  why is only one of them covered with []

Comment: `[]` will be used when you are passing an expression or value(which will be evaluated later). Without `[]` means you are passing static value.